# How to reference an object of a class in a statement?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the top of my form I have:

```
public static int hoursInt;
public static int minutesInt;
public static int secondsInt;
public static int CompletedIn24;
```

Then further down I have the following to reset the `numericUpDown` boxes to zero when selecting a new runner:

```
private void lstRunners_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;

numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
numericUpDown2.Value = 0;
numericUpDown3.Value = 0;
}
```

Then in the `Finish` button click event I have:

```
 hoursInt = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
 minutesInt = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);
 secondsInt = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value);

if (lstRunners.SelectedIndex > -1 && hoursInt + minutesInt + secondsInt != 0)
        {
            // Obtain selected climber
            Runner selectedRunner = (Runner)lstRunners.SelectedItem;
            selectedRunner.Hours = hoursInt;
            selectedRunner.Minutes = minutesInt;
            selectedRunner.Seconds = secondsInt;

            var expertRunner = selectedRunner as Expert;
            if (expertRunner != null)
            {
                expertRunner.UponFinish();
            }
```

Here is my overriden method in `Expert : Runner`:

```
public override void UponFinish()
        {
            base.UponFinish();

            // The integer must increment by one if the time is 24:00:00 or less i.e. 23:59:59 would increment the integer as well
            if (Hours < 24 || (Hours == 24 && Minutes == 0 && Seconds == 0))
            {
                CompletedIn24++;
            }
        }
```

At present the `UponFinish()` method in `Runner` doesn't have anything inside the braces as I'm not sure if anything is required?

I tried to output the `CompletedIn24` integer to a string to see if it would work when the button is clicked but the value stayed at zero even if an expert runner was selected and the time was 24:00:00 or less. The integer is not incrementing and I'm not sure what is causing the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you have to check if the runner is ExpertRunner if you have UponFinish() in the base class as well? Just call UponFinish()? How is your lstRunners populated? Does it contain both Runner and ExpertRunner?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Yes it does, the lstRunners is populated with an array that has various types of climbers in it

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `as` keyword like this:

```
var runner = selectedRunner as Expert;
if(runner != null) runner.UponFinish();
```

If your class `Runner` already defines some method called `UponFinish`, you should define this method as `virtual` and override that method in the derived classes, like this:

```
public class Runner {
  public virtual void UponFinish(){
     //...
  }
}
public class Expert : Runner {
  public override void UponFinish(){
    //You talked about the time, I asked for clarification on this
    //but it's still very unclear. I suppose when you mean the time is 24:00:00
    //that means the hours is 24, the minutes is 0 and the seconds is 0
    if(Hours < 24 || (Minutes == 0 && Seconds == 0)) Completedin24++;
  }
}
```

Then of course you don't need any cast, just call `UponFinish` and the overridden code (if any) will be called correctly:

```
selectedRunner.UponFinish();
```

Comment: I would use var expertRunner instead of runner and space between "if(" but still closest to what I would've done.

Comment: OK. On my form I have variables such as `selectedRunner.Hours = hoursInt` and the same for `Minutes` and `Seconds.` then I have `hoursInt = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);`. In the overriden `UponFinish()` method, how would I basically format it to say if the time is 24:00:00 or less, increase the integer given that the hours, minutes and seconds are split up into three integers? Thanks for the help so far, the code seems to work fine.

Comment: @user2929108 which integer of three ones do you want to increase? Where is the `time` from?

Comment: @KingKing Oh sorry. I have an integer called `Completedin24` and basically want that integer to increment only for Expert runners if their time is 24:00:00 or below. I've defined the int at the top of my form `public static int Completedin24;`.

Comment: @user2929108 what about the time, how is the time composed? is there any field or property about the time or we can compose the time from `hoursInt`, `minutesInt` and `secondsInt` like this `hoursInt : minutesInt : secondsInt`?

Comment: @KingKing the three ints `public static int hoursInt` are defined at the top of the form then as you see the ints are set to the value of each `numericUpDown`, 1 for hours, minutes and seconds, then I've done `selectedRunner.Hours = hoursInt`, `selectedRunner.Minutes = minutesInt` and `selectedRunner.Seconds = secondsInt` since the `Runner` class has `public int Hours` then `get { return hours; } set { hours = value; }`

Comment: @user2929108 see the update, if it's still not what you want, you should update your question to make it clear.

Comment: @KingKing Updated the question to make it a bit more clear now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40757/discussion-between-user2929108-and-king-king)

Answer (score 0):

You can check type like this:

```
if (selectedRunner.GetType() == typeof(Expert))
{
    Expert expert = (Expert)selectedRunner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if(selectedRunner is Expert)
{
    UponFinish((Expert)selectedRunner);
    //or ((Expert)selectedRunner).UponFinish(); if that was the intention
}
```

or alternatively

```
Expert selectedExpert = selectedRunner as Expert;
if(selectedExpert != null)
    UponFinish(selectedExpert);
```

edit:

If your `UponFinish` function is already part of both `Runner` and `Expert` (that is, overridden in `Expert`), you don't need to cast selectedRunner before calling it.

Comment: I updated my question, if you could check it out I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, exists the operator `is` for example:
[Operator IS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your Runner is an ExpertRunner by using the is keyword:

```
if(selectedRunner is ExpertRunner)
```

However, in terms of OOP you should never have to do this, you may want to check your hierarchy or logic why you need to handle this case seperately and not in overridden behaviour (function or properties).

Comment: I updated my question, if you could check it out I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(lstRunners.SelectedItem is Expert)
{
    Expert selectedRunner = lstRunners.SelectedItem as Expert;
    selectedRunner.UponFinish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (lstRunners.SelectedItem is Expert)
{
    ((Expert)lstRunners.SelectedItem).UponFinish();
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, if you could check it out I'd be grateful